# Difference between SqlCeCommand and SqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net

In my current project I found myself in need for a connection to a database.

However in the new asp.net 5.0 I found myself in the position where I could only find S`qlCeCommand`.

So now is my question is there or what is the difference between `SqlCeCommand` and `SqlCommand`?

`SqlCeCommand` is a class from `System.Data.SqlServerCe`; and `SqlCommand` is a class from `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: `SqlCommand` = server-based **SQL Server** (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise); `SqlCeCommand` = SQL Server **Compact Edition** - based on a `.sdf` file, single-user, used for local storage only, embedded by including some DLL's in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlCeCommand` is a specialized command that can be used to talk to the compact edition of the SQL Server ([SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)). `SqlCommand` is a specialized command that can be used to talk to the regular Microsoft SQL Server. Both inherit from `DbCommand`, a generic version independent from the target database type and version.

We usually work with `IDbCommand` to be independent from provider-specific features, which makes it easier to migrate to another database engine. The connection as well as command are retrieved from a factory.